# Subsetting multiple dataframes within list in R based on strings in another dataframe

Tags: r, loops, subset

I am trying to subset multiple dataframes that are contained in a list based on strings that are contained in another dataframe.

```
list.df <- list(
 df.1 = data.frame(LM = c(1:10), LS = c(1:10), PL = c(1:10)), 
 df.2 = data.frame(XY = c(1:10), FE = c(4:13), OI = c(1:10)), 
 df.3 = data.frame(IL = c(1:10), KU = c(9:18), TS = c(1:10)))

df.4 <- data.frame(df.1 = c("LM", "PL", NA), df.2 = c("FE", NA, NA), 
 df.3 = c("IL", "KU", "TS"))
```

I want all my dataframes to look like this in the end:

```
df.1_sub <- subset(list.df[["df.1"]], select = 
   colnames(list.df[["df.1"]]) %in% df.4$df.1)
```

I will have to do this for around 50 datasets and was wondering whether there was a way of writing a loop to do this for all the datasets at once.

I have tried using lapply and for loops but was so far unsuccessful. I am new to using lists in R and would appreciate any help! 
This is my first time posting on stack overflow so please let me know if my post isn't appropriate,

Comment: Just to clarify, if you created `df.2_sub` it would just be the `FE` column, correct? And `df.3_sub` would be a 10x3 dataframe consisting of columns `IL`, `KU`, and `TS`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `Map` would be to remove `NA` values from `df.4` and subset the respective columns from `list.df`

```
Map(function(x, y) x[as.character(na.omit(y))], list.df, df.4)

#$df.1
#   LM PL
#1   1  1
#2   2  2
#3   3  3
#4   4  4
#5   5  5
#6   6  6
#7   7  7
#8   8  8
#9   9  9
#10 10 10

#$df.2
#   FE
#1   4
#2   5
#3   6
#4   7
#5   8
#6   9
#7  10
#8  11
#9  12
#10 13

#$df.3
#   IL KU TS
#1   1  9  1
#2   2 10  2
#3   3 11  3
#.....
```

The same can be achieved using `purrr::map2`

```
purrr::map2(list.df, df.4, ~.x[na.omit(as.character(.y))])
```

Comment: Too fast for me. `Map` instead of `mapply` probably makes more sense since you aren't simplifying the result though.

Comment: it's a pity `df.4` has `factor` columns or you could collapse significantly - `Map(\`[\`, list.df, lapply(df.4, na.omit))` - which unfortunately gives the wrong answer currently.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies! I have tried the above and it works fine on the example but when I try to do it for my actual data I get this error `Error: Can't find columns `AD`, `AB`, `AW`, `AC`, `AL`, ... (and 32 more) in `.data`. I have check manually, an these columns are definitely in one of the dataframes in the list. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ricarda This is not working for all the dataframes in the list. This subsets first column of `df.4` with first list in `list.df[[1]]`, second column of `df.4` is subsetted with `list.df[[2]]` and so on. Are you trying to subset it from entire `list.df` ?

Comment: @Ronak, Thanks! I just realised that the order of the columns in `df.4` isn't the same as the order of the dfs in `list.df`. Basically, there is one column in `df.4` that corresponds to one of the dfs in the list.That column and the dataframe have the same name.

Comment: @Ricarda ok..in that case we need to re-order either the list or the dataframe. Try doing `Map(function(x, y) x[as.character(na.omit(y))], list.df[names(df.4)], df.4)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `complete.cases` with `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) x[complete.cases(y)], list.df, df.4)
#$df.1
#   LM LS
#1   1  1
#2   2  2
#3   3  3
#4   4  4
#5   5  5
#6   6  6
#7   7  7
#8   8  8
#9   9  9
#10 10 10

#$df.2
#   XY
#1   1
#2   2
#3   3
#4   4
#5   5
#6   6
#7   7
#8   8
#9   9
#10 10

#$df.3
#   IL KU TS
#1   1  9  1
#2   2 10  2
#3   3 11  3
#4   4 12  4
#5   5 13  5
#6   6 14  6
#7   7 15  7
#8   8 16  8
#9   9 17  9
#10 10 18 10
```

---

Or using `pmap`

```
library(purrr)  
pmap(list(list.df, df.4), ~ .x[complete.cases(.y)])
```